# Spring Data Cassandra not allowing to fetch page 2 without pageState

Tags: cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I'm developing Apache Cassandra based Spring application. I'm using Spring Data Cassandra for persistence layer. When I tried to fetch a non-zero page as described in [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/) I'm getting a IllegalArgumentException saying *Cannot create a Cassandra page request for an indexed page other than the first page (0).* It is thrown from,

```
public static CassandraPageRequest of(int page, int size) {
    Assert.isTrue(page == 0, "Cannot create a Cassandra page request for an indexed page other than the first page (0).");
    return of(page, size, Sort.unsorted());
}
```

method of the library.

Am I doing something that violates Cassandra design/usage principles?

Does this mean Spring data Cassandra is designed to fetch only from page one and if we want next  pages do we have to cache pageState and  fetch next ones?

And if why this framework doesn't allow to fetch other pages?

Is there a architectural or a technical reason? (documentation doesn't provide these information. At least that we need to use page state for fetching next ones.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cassandra supports paging only by fetching the next page. Limit/offset is not applicable.

> Cassandra repositories support paging and sorting for paginated and sorted access to the entities. Cassandra paging requires a paging state to forward-only navigate through pages. A Slice keeps track of the current paging state and allows the creation of a Pageable to request the next page.

That said, the answer to your question

> Does this mean Spring data Cassandra is designed to fetch only from page one and if we want next pages do we have to cache pageState and fetch next ones?

is yes.

Paging in Spring Data assumes pagination via limit/offset as most supported data stores follow this pattern. Pagination in Cassandra follows more an `Iterator` style.

Comment: Thank you very much for quick reply and solving the issue.

Comment: Hi Could you please share me the Cached approach steps which you have implemented to cache Cassandra paging State

Comment: I cant reconcile this Spring Data functionality to this https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.5/manual/core/paging/. Is it simply a limitation that with Spring Data, we always have to fetch page 0, and then move from there vs. with the Java Driver, i can supply a (non-zero) pageState? Is it planned that org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.query.CassandraPageRequest will support non-zero page in future? Thanks