# Cassandra page request for an indexed page other than the first page

Tags: spring-boot, pagination, spring-data-cassandra

Java: 19

Springboot: 3.0

Dependency:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Repository:

```
PersonRepository extends ReactiveCassandraRepository<Person, Integer> {
    Mono<Slice<Person>> findAll(Pageable page);
    Mono<Slice<Person>> findAllByType(String type, Pageable page);
}
```

Service:

```
 public Mono<Slice<Person>> findPaginatedPerson(int limit, int offset) {

    int page = offset / limit;
    //only working with page = 0
    Pageable pageRequest = CassandraPageRequest.of(page,limit); 
    Mono<Slice<Person>> persons = personRepository.findAll(pageRequest);


    //working for first page only
   //Mono<Slice<Person>> persons = personRepository.findAll(CassandraPageRequest.first(1));
    return persons;
  }
```

Controller:

```
 @GetMapping("/persons")
  public List<Person> findPaginated(@RequestParam int limit, @RequestParam int offset) {
    Mono<Slice<Person>> personPage = personService.findPaginatedPerson(limit, offset);
    return personPage.block().getContent();
  }
```

paagination is only working for 1st page, for the next page getting error "Cannot create a Cassandra page request for an indexed page other than the first page (0)"

There is one related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49843645/5321614), but not giving enough information which will be helpful to me.

I tried using Slice directly like

```
 public List<Person> findFoo(int limit, int offset) {
    int page = offset / limit;
    int currpage = 0, size = 2;
    Pageable pageRequest = CassandraPageRequest.of(size, limit);
    Slice< Person > persons = personRepository.findAllByAssetType(pageRequest);
    while(persons.hasNext() && currpage < page) {
      persons = personRepository.findAllByAssetType(persons.nextPageable());
      currpage++;
    }
    return persons.getContent();
  }
```

but this also gives same error.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

```
public List<Person> findPaginatedPerson(int limit, int offset) {
    int page =0;
    int noOfrecords = offset * limit;

    Pageable pageRequest = CassandraPageRequest.of(page, noOfrecords);
    Mono<Slice<Person>> persons = personRepository.findAll(pageRequest);
    return persons.block().getContent().stream().skip(noOfrecords-limit).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Here I am collecting (records per page * number of page) numbers of records till current page and skipping (records per page * (number of page-1)) which is number of records till last page and returning it.

This is quite inefficient, so looking for a better solution.

if I will keep the fetched data in memory and skip that after fetching again, that also will be inefficient.